# Pass session values from action to servlet in seam framework

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, seam

I am setting the session object in TestAction class and when i am trying to get the session object in TestServlet it returns null. Any one please tell me how to pass session from action class to servlet in Seam framework.

```
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@Name("testAction  ")
public class TestAction  {

    public void setSessionObj(){

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("temp", "124563");
    }
}
```

//Servlet starts here

```
 public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

        public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
            super.init(servletConfig);
            servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();

        }

        protected String doExecute(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                 Session session =    request.getSession(false);
            String user1 = (String) session .getAttribute("temp");
        }
    }
```

Below is the observation on debugging the session instances

I checked session object instance in case of what i am getting in action and servlet, they both are different instances of Session. For e.g instance in action is StandardSession[41CBDED6EBBBECEBA001A70555F51CA5] and what i m getting in servlet is StandardSession[EACBDED6E34BECEB3401A70555F51CA5], Any reason why i am getting different session instances

Comment: How about request.getSession() ?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the servlet?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need to access the session attributes via the `FacesContext` in your servlet. Just use `request.getSession()` to get the session. As long as your requests are actually from the same session, the session attributes should be available in the servlet.

Comment: i have tried using request.getSession also, it gives me null, when i check object name in case of what i get in action and servlet, they both are different instances of Session. For e.g instance in action is StandardSession[41CBDED6EBBBECEBA001A70555F51CA5] and what i m getting in servlet is StandardSession[EACBDED6E34BECEB3401A70555F51CA5]

Comment: If they have different session ids, then they are not the same session, and hence they won't be able to see each other session attributes, no matter what you try.

Comment: Yes that is the trouble i have, why they are having different session ids, when requests are made on same session

Comment: Well, then they are not made on the same session.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a proxy-object that gets injected via CDI / Spring into both the JSF Managed Bean and the servlet.

This example creates an CDI Bean with is kept alive during the whole time and just stores a String. Trough dependecy injection both components can access it.

Create an empty bean.xml file under META-INF resource folder

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Container{
 private String temp;

 public Container(){

 }
 public void setTemp(String temp) {
  this.temp = temp;
 }

 public String getTemp() {
  return temp;
 }
}

@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@Name("testAction  ")
public class TestAction  {

 @Inject 
 Container container;

public void setSessionObj(){
 container.setTemp("123456");

}
}
```

//Servlet starts here

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
Container container; 
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servletConfig);
        servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();

    }

    protected String doExecute(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

             Session session =    request.getSession(false);
        String user1 = container.getTemp();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample example

Comment: Bad advice. This is going to be shared across **all** visitors/users of the application.